# Not able use Angular material tab component in my angularcli application

Tags: angular-material2

I have an existing angular CLI project and I started using the angular material in that project, I did all the installation part and I import angular material as well. So here when am trying to use md-tab directive, I am not able to see any changes and error as well in the console. tried to look for the solution but I dint get anything thing.
Can some one please help on this.

Comment: Please state your version of Angular Material 2 and whether you have already imported a theme in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the `MdTabModule` in your app's module file?

```ts
@NgModule([
    imports: [
        MdTabModule
    ]
])
export class AppModule {}
```

Note: You should not import `MaterialModule` since it will be deprecated in a subsequent release and thus just import only the modules you need:

```ts
const MY_MATERIAL_MODULES = [
    MdButtonModule,
    // ...
]

@NgModule([
    imports: [MY_MATERIAL_MODULES]
    exports: [MY_MATERIAL_MODULES]
)]
export class MyMaterialModule {}
// ...
@NgModule([
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        // ...
        MyMaterialModule
    ]
])
export class AppModule {}
```